# bitcoin.conf file is missing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin.conf

Just installed bitcoin core v0.21.0 on my ubuntu server.
When I run

> bitcoind -printtoconsole

It says bitcoin.conf file is missing.

> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Bitcoin Core version v0.21.0 (release build)
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Assuming ancestors of block 0000000000000000000b9d2ec5a352ecba0592946514a92f14319dc2b367fc72 have valid signatures.
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=00000000000000000000000000000000000000001533efd8d716a517fe2c5008
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Using the 'shani(1way,2way)' SHA256 implementation
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Using RdSeed as additional entropy source
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Using RdRand as an additional entropy source
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z No wallet support compiled in!
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Default data directory /root/.bitcoin
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Using data directory /root/.bitcoin
> 2021-01-30T15:36:58Z Config file: /root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf (not found, skipping)

As I know, it should be in $HOME/.bitcoin folder. But it's not. Should I create it manually?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It hasn't been created automatically, at least for as long as I remember.

But not in the folder whose screesnhot you've uploaded.